# SQL Server - Create View with rows from multiple result sets

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following queries

```
Select Count(*) From TableA

Select Count(*) From TableB

Select Count(*) From TableC

Select Count(*) From TableD
```

I want to return a view like:

```
-----------
| Counts  |
-----------
| 2       | --from TableA
-----------
| 3       | --from TableB
----------
| 4       | --from TableC
----------
| 5       | --from TableD
----------
```

I tried using UNION e.g:

```
CREATE VIEW [Foo]
AS
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Counts]
FROM TableA
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TableB
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TableC
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TableD
```

But the order was incorrect

```
-----------
| Counts  |
-----------
| 2       | --from TableA
-----------
| 3       | --from TableB
----------
| 5       | --from TableD
----------
| 4       | --from TableC
----------
```

Is there an alternative besides UNION I can use to produce the result set I want?

Comment: Are you using the order to identify which table each count comes from?

Comment: I want the order to be from A to D

Comment: Yes, I'm just curious as to why. Often it's best not to rely on a view to be ordered.

Comment: Why would you not include the table names, so you know what the result set means?

Answer (score 2):

Very close, just add a derived field for your order.

```
CREATE VIEW [Foo]
AS
SELECT TOP(100) PERCENT
*
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Counts], RowOrder=1
    FROM TableA
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*), 2
    FROM TableB
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*), 3
    FROM TableC
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*), 4
    FROM TableD
)AS X
ORDER BY RowOrder
```

OR - Order outside of the count view.

```
CREATE VIEW [Foo]
AS
SELECT 
*
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Counts], RowOrder=1
    FROM TableA
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*), 2
    FROM TableB
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*), 3
    FROM TableC
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*), 4
    FROM TableD
)AS X

...
SELECT * FROM Foo ORDER BY RowOrder
```

Comment: Order by in a view makes no sense and isn't possible without also specifying top. The ONLY way to ensure order in a result set is to use an order by on the final select statement. BTW, ordering by ordinal position is often considered a bad idea.

Comment: Doh! you are right you need a top 100 PERCENT which is not normally used. Alos, I let my shorthand get the best of me from quick scripting habbits, thanks Sean Lange.

Answer (score 1):

`UNION` internally does the sorting for you, you need `union all` or define explicit ordring instead :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Counts]
FROM TableA UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TableB UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TableC UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TableD;
```

You can also define explicit ordering :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Counts], 1 as SortOrder
FROM TableA UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*), 2
FROM TableB UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*), 3
FROM TableC UNION 
SELECT COUNT(*), 4
FROM TableD;
```

So, you need to use `order by` clause in view `Foo`

```
select f.*
from Foo f
order by SortOrder;
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: UNION ALL does NOT guarantee the order. It in fact has nothing to do with order. UNION returns only distinct rows where UNION ALL return all the rows. There is one and only one way to ensure order, using an ORDER BY statement in the final query.

Comment: UNION ALL will return duplicates.  What if duplicates aren't wanted?

Comment: You can't put an order by in a view unless you also specify top. And in the view it is NOT guaranteed to return in that order in the final select statement. What happens if you have two views which are "ordered" and the ordering logic conflicts with each other?

Comment: @JeffOrris What duplicates are  you referring to in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Views return *unordered* result sets.  You could try to do:

```
create view v_counts as
    select . . .
    order by . . .
```

And you'll get the error message:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

As the message suggests, there is a way to cheat to get around this, but I advise against it -- even when you cheat, the view is not *guaranteed* to return results in order.

Instead, include the table name:

```
Select 'TableA' as which, Count(*) From TableA
union all
Select 'TableB' as which, Count(*) From TableB
union all
Select 'TableC' as which, Count(*) From TableC
union all
Select 'TableD' as which, Count(*) From TableD;
```